# Webpack style-loader appendChild no CSP friendly

Tags: security, webpack, content-security-policy, webpack-style-loader

Content Security Policy (CSP) doesn't like how webpack's style-loader is using `appendChild`. Any ideas how to customize these tools to work together?

Answer (score 4):

There is a new `attr` option in style-loader allowing you to add custom attributes to the `<script>` tag. I am using it to add a `nonce` attr :

```
{
  loader: 'style-loader',
  options: {
    attrs: {
      nonce: 'devOnly',
    }
  }
}
```

Then I added this nonce to my CSP policy, only for the development environment (you should use `ExtractTextPlugin` for production anyway) :
`style-src 'self' 'nonce-devOnly'`

Comment: Based on the new API, `attrs` has been changed to `attributes` https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#attributes